# How to make it run the `exec()` command in PHP to edit some file in Mac OS X?

Tags: php, macos, protocols, exec

When I have this PHP script.

```
<?php
    exec('/usr/local/bin/mate hello.txt');
?>
```

It doesn't work on web browser with http://abc/hello.php, for example.

The command of mate is 'TextMate app', and it's just for editing hello.txt.

Is this some php permission problem?
I just need to run some commands on my local web server (I'm the only user), so I can open the permission to run this seemingly dangerous `exec()` function.

- Q : How can I make it run the PHP `exec()` function?

I use Mac OS X 10.6.6/Apache/PHP5.

### ADDED

I guess it's not possible to launch something with PHP on my Mac, but for my purposes to open an TextMate editor to edit something, using txmt protocol works perfectly fine.

### SOLVED

In terms of launching an Application in web browser (especially Safari) cannot be done with php, but with protocol handler.

#### Launching TextEditor to edit something.

TextEditor provides its own protocol handler `txmt://open/?url=file://THE_FILE_TO_EDIT"`.

Or, you can have a button to  edit the file when clicked.

```
<form action="txmt://open/?url=file://FILE_TO_EDIT" method="post">
  <button type="submit">Edit</button>
</form>
```

#### Launching other app

You need to come up with your own protocol handler.  has all the necessary information with an example.

For example, for launching PathFinder

Make URL types/schemes at Info.plist.

You may want to main window that pops up. You can set `Application is agent`.

[image]

Make the `pf:` protocol handler.

It just analyzes the input of `pf:INPUT_GINVEN`, to get the `INPUT_GIVEN` part to give it as a parameter to PathFInder.

```
@implementation URLHandlerCommand!
- (id)performDefaultImplementation {
    NSString *urlString = [self directParameter];

    NSLog(@"url :=: %@", urlString);

    NSArray *components = [urlString componentsSeparatedByString: @":"];
    NSString* string2 = (NSString*) [components objectAtIndex:1];

    NSLog(@"url :=: %@", string2);

    [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] openFile:string2 withApplication:@"Path Finder"];
    [[NSApplication sharedApplication] terminate:nil];

    return nil;
}
```

@end

Use the `pf:OPEN_DIRECTORY` protocol.

```
<form action="pf:DIRECORY_TO_OPEN" method="post">
    <button type="submit">Open</button>
</form>
```

Comment: By any chance is `my_editor` an interactive program?  Meaning does it actually interact with you if you launch it in a shell?

Comment: Are you saying you want to use a php script to open an editor on your machine?

Comment: @Dalton : Yes, I am. I just want to use Web browser to control things if it is possible.

Comment: @ircmaxell : No, my_editor is just TextMate program.

Comment: @John because php is not an application manager by any means. @prosseek I wouldn't suggest doing this in php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the script is running on a remote web server, then the `exec()` will run on the remote server, *not* the local machine. My guess is you want the command run on the local computer that is visiting the website, but this is not possible for very good (security) reasons.

What you probably want to use is the `txmt://` protocol as described in the [Textmate Manual](http://manual.macromates.com/en/using_textmate_from_terminal.html):

```
<a href="txmt://open/?url=file://~/.bash_profile&line=11&column=2">Open in Textmate</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for letting me the txmt:// protocol, I guess I can use this protocol to get the same result that I expect.

Answer (score 2):

You are doing it right.  Try running something else like `ls` and see if that works.  When you run that command, does it show some output then return you to a prompt?  If it doesn't, then you're not going to get anything by running it through exec in PHP.  You are not going to be able to run a command line editor in the browser.

Comment: I got nothing by running 'exec('ls')'.

Comment: @prosseek There may be other problems, but its likely the fact that you are trying to run something that isn't going to just run and output something, then return to prompt.  Try this code, and see if you get anything, if you do your exec command is working fine. `echo exec('pwd');`

Comment: +1 "You are not going to be able to run a command line editor in the browser."